# Find patterns across multiple log files?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have eight log files in the following format:

log01:

```
[Tue Feb 24 07:39:37 2015] *** MARK ***
[Tue Feb 24 07:40:38 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:13:33 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:14:09 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:16:46 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:17:48 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:22:31 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:10:36 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:10:52 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:11:08 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:11:34 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:12:00 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:12:26 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:13:17 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:13:33 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:15:05 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:37:53 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:38:19 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:38:35 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:08:47 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:09:28 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:11:55 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:12:21 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:12:52 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:13:08 2015] *** MARK ***
...
```

log02:

```
[Wed Feb 25 07:01:39 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:13:49 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:15:20 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:16:47 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:17:38 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:19:56 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 17:22:53 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:10:47 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:11:13 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:11:34 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:11:50 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:12:11 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:12:37 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:12:53 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:13:14 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:13:40 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:14:06 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:14:22 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:14:38 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 19:38:30 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 21:17:08 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:08:56 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:10:37 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:11:08 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:11:24 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:12:20 2015] *** MARK ***
[Wed Feb 25 23:12:46 2015] *** MARK ***
...
```

Every log file is generated by an instance of the same program reading different sensors. A log entry is created if a sensor detects an issue. If every sensor detects an issue within about a minute, it indicates a global problem has occured. For example:

The log entries `[Tue Feb 24 07:39:37 2015] *** MARK ***` and `[Tue Feb 24 07:40:38 2015] *** MARK ***` from log01 do not corresponds to anything in log02 so this is not a global problem and can be ignored. The log entries `[Wed Feb 25 07:01:39 2015] *** MARK ***` and `[Wed Feb 25 21:17:08 2015] *** MARK ***` in log02 can also be ignored.

However, entry `[Wed Feb 25 19:10:36 2015] *** MARK ***` in log01 and `[Wed Feb 25 19:10:47 2015] *** MARK ***` in log02 is within a minute so this indicates a global problem that lasts until entry `[Wed Feb 25 19:15:05 2015] *** MARK ***` in log01 and `[Wed Feb 25 19:14:38 2015] *** MARK ***` in log02. So I can conclude that from around 19:10 to 19:15 on Feb 25 something was wrong.

I'm looking for suggestions and tips on how to approach this problem, preferably by using UNIX utilities.

Comment: S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to have attempted to solve your problem and we help with fixing your problems. Good luck.

Comment: How do you detect the ending time of a problem?

Comment: shellter: It was not my intention to have anyone code anything for free. Because of the date format I'm not sure if it's possible at all, so I was hoping for suggestions on how to approach this. Trying to describe a problem for others will make you think different about it, and this sometimes reveals the solution.

Comment: Mark Setchell: A problem is detected if all log files have an entry that is within a minute of each other, as soon as this pattern stops the problem has ended, and the end time will be the most current time while the pattern lasted, for example `Wed Feb 25 19:15:05 2015` in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the elegant way would be to use Perl to read all the files in and create an array of lists. The first array would be indexed by the time rounded to the nearest minute, and you would push a `1` onto the list at a given time if you were reading from `file01` and a `2` if you were reading from `file02`. Then at the end, you would iterate through the first array looking for lists with length greater than one. A `Perl` tag might help there.

If you don't like Perl, you could put something clumsier together, like this.

Step 1: Choose a start time earlier than the earliest time you want.

Step 2: Parse each file, outputting one line per minute of input data. That line is either 0 or 1 depending whether there is a problem or not. One line per minute ensures that all the files *line up* matching the minute across all 8.

Step 3: Use `paste` to put all the 8 output files together like this:

```
paste -d, file{1..8}

1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1
1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Step 4: Use `awk` to look for lines that add up to more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in $(awk -F' ' '{print $4;}' log01 | cut -c1-5)
do
    if (grep -q $n log02)
    then
        echo "Error on $n"
    fi
done
```

- The command `awk -F' ' '{print $4;}' log01 | cut -c1-5` extracts the hour (`hh:mm`) from your `log01` file.
- `grep -q $n log02` search for this hour and report and error if found it.

Comment: What about the other 6 log files?

Comment: What about `if (grep -q $n log02) && (grep -q $n log03) && ...`?

Comment: Mmmm, if there is no problem in `log01` for a given time, you aren't going to look in the other logs, so there could be problems in all 7 others and you would never find them.

Comment: Maybe the OP must explain that kind of things. Can be lots of variables that neither you nor me knows. As starting point seems a useful answer to me.

Comment: jherran: Thanks for your suggestion. The log files will need to be split in dates, but that's no problem. However, the problem may not be present in log01 first. The first entry could be in log06, but if an entry is created in all the other log files within a minute, a global problem has occured.